# why the object of my code is outputing undefined if it has a value? I compared my code with other similar ones that work and I can't see the error

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I am trying to `console.log` the `typeOne`(or any other type) property of each object in the `donuts` array, but I keep getting `undefined` as the output. My editor is showing that the problem is at the colon character in the object literals, suggesting that I should print a comma instead. However, I believe that is incorrect. What is the issue here and how can I fix it?

```js
var donuts = [
  { typeOne: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { typeTwo: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { typeThree: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { typeFour: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];
console.log(donuts.typeOne);
//or
console.log(donuts["typeOne"]); //both console.log shows undefined
```

Comment: Use `donuts[0].typeOne`. `donuts` is an array, not an object, so you need to access its elements with indices. On the other hand, `typeOne` is a bad property name, since no other object has such a property. Use `name` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your example donuts is an array not an object (it's an array of objects). To print the first item, you have to write donuts[0].typeOne. You are getting undefined because you are treating the donuts variable as an object instead of an array.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because `donuts` is an array. You can reference items in an array by their indexes.

For example:

```js
var donuts = [
  { typeOne: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { typeTwo: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { typeThree: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { typeFour: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];

console.log(donuts[0].typeOne);
//or
console.log(donuts[1]["typeTwo"]);
```

You could make things are little more interesting if you change `type<Number>` to `name` and do something like this:

```js
var donuts = [
  { name: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { name: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { name: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { name: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];
    
console.log(donuts.find(d => d.name == "Chocolate").cost);
//or
console.log(donuts.filter(d => d.cost < 2.0 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the property `typeOne` directly from donuts. But donuts is an array of objects, not a direct object. If you want to get the property `typeOne` from each object in your array, you need to go at each item with some method like `map`:

```js
var result = donuts.map((donut) => donut.typeOne)
```

Problem is, the property `typeOne` only exists in the first object of your array, so `result` here will be ["Jelly", undefined, undefined, undefined]

To list all types from each object in your array I suggest this:

```js
var donuts = [
  { type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];

var result = donuts.map((donut) => donut.type)
```

In this case, `type` is a property in every object, so when you use `map` you iterate through all the objects in your array and get the value of the property `type`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

So your object "typeOne", is an an array.
You have to access the object in the array, then the objects properties.

```js
//you declare and object like this
var obj = {
   key: 'value'
};
console.log(obj.key);

//you declare a array like this
var array = [
    'val1',
    'val2'
];
//to access a arrays value you have to use its index
console.log(array[0])//index starts at zero in javascipt, not one

//so if you have a object in a array, like here
var donuts = [
  { typeOne: &quot;Jelly&quot;, cost: 1.22 },
  { typeTwo: &quot;Chocolate&quot;, cost: 2.45 },
  { typeThree: &quot;Cider&quot;, cost: 1.59 },
  { typeFour: &quot;Boston Cream&quot;, cost: 5.99 
]
//you first have to, you first have to get the object using by its index
console.log(donuts[0])//the arrays firsts value: {typeOne etc)

//so now to access the arrays object properties, just get the object from the array first like above, then the properties
console.log(donuts[0].typeOne)

//or you can get the second object
console.log(donuts[1].typeTwo)
```